# Regular Expression to replace dot with space before parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I am working on some customer comments that some of them did not follow grammatical rules. For Example `(Such as s and b.)` in the following text that provides more explanation for previous sentence is surrounded by two dots.

```
   text = "I was initially scared of ANY drug after my experience. But about a year later I tried. (Such as s and b.). I had a very bad reaction to this."
```

First, I want to find `. (Such as s and b.).` and then  replace the  dot before `(Such as s and b.)` to space. This is my code, but it does not work.

```
text = re.sub (r'(\.)(\s+?\(.+\)\s*\.)', r' \2 ', text )
```

Output should be:

```
 "I was initially scared of ANY drug after my experience. But about a year later I tried  (Such as s and b.). I had a very bad reaction to this."
```

I am using python.

Comment: Are the `\`` always there, too? I guess you need to include them into the pattern.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, No I edited the text.

Comment: Your pattern should be `r'(\.)(\s+\(.+?\)\s*\.)'` and the replacement needs to be `r' \2'`. Or, try this - [`re.sub (r'\.(\s+\([^)]*\)\s*\.)', r' \1', text )`](http://ideone.com/rFGpqj)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, but it does not work. The dot before " . (Such as s and b.)."  did not remove.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, your second answer woks very well.  "re.sub (r'\.(\s+\([^)]*\)\s*\.)', r' \1', text )" . Thank you !

Comment: Trincot's update works the same. Almost.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,  trincot's solution also removed dot before before paranthesis in the following sentence: "I was tired. (This was 10 years ago) and I was not there." As you see (This was 10 years ago) was not surrounded by two dots.

Comment: [I can't repro](https://regex101.com/r/qKXooJ/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample provided does not make much sense because the only change is that the ` character is moved one position to the left.

However, this might do the trick (to keep the dot inside the paranthesis):

```
text = re.sub(r'\.\s*\)\s*\.', '.)', text)
```

Or this to have it outside:

```
text = re.sub(r'\.\s*\)\s*\.', ').', text)
```

**Edit:** Or maybe you're looking for this to replace the dot before the opening paranthesis?

```
text = re.sub(r'\.(?=\s*\(.*?\)\.)', ').', text)
```

Comment: The regular expression should be able to find  " . (Such as s and b.). " that was surrounded by two dots and then remove the first dot.

Comment: The third one should do just that. :)

Comment: Thank you ! second and third solution work. But the first one does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this to remove a dot before parentheses when there is another one following them:

```
text = re.sub(r'\.(\s*?\([^)]*\)\s*\.)', r'\1', text)
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/DrvM/3)

Comment: First I need to find all the parentheses that were surrounded by two dots. for example:  ". ( abc)." or ". (aaaaa.) ." and remove the fist dot. So I do not need to find parentheses in this sentence : " I went to school (but the weather was warm). "

Comment: But in your example you made a second change and placed the dot differently after the closing parenthesis. Was that a typo? Oh I see you updated your question....

Comment: OK, I was mislead by the backticks that occurred in your original question version. Updated my answer.

Comment: your solution also removed dot before before paranthesis in the following sentence: 
"I was tired. (This was 10 years ago) and  I was not there."  As you see (This was 10 years ago) was not surrounded by two dots.

Comment: Strange, you must have tried this with a different regular expression, as it does not remove the dot in that example: https://repl.it/DrvM/2

Comment: I did just now fix another issue, that is when you have pairs of several opening and closing parentheses, it should only look at the first pair. That is fixed now.

Comment: Yeah, now it looks next to identical to my suggestion and should work.

Comment: Note to myself: when @WiktorStribiżew says something about regex, it is very likely to be right ;-)